# intersectioncalculation not working

Tags: android, 2d, line-intersection

I am doing a game for a schoolproject that will use a calculation for seing if two lines intersects.

I am not very good at the math behind calculating intersections but I have found a couple of examples on how it works, on this site for example. But I don't get them to work.

I have made a image of how I have tried to detect intersection and comparing it to the calculationexample i have found, and why it is not working. Somewhere i have been doing wrong but I cant find out where.

If anyone could help me I would be very thankful.

Regards Micke
[image]